# MQTTnet and AWS IOT - can connect and publish, can't subscribe

Tags: c#, .net, mqtt, aws-iot, mqttnet

I am trying to write a POC using `MQTTnet` and `AWS IOT`.  I can successfully connect and publish messages, but as soon as I subscribe the connection is closed with    `MqttClientDisconnectedException`

- topic is "vin/my-vin"
- MQTTnet 4.2.1.781
- .NET 7 - console app

connect - works

```
var mqttFactory = new MqttFactory();

mqttClient = mqttFactory.CreateMqttClient();

var mqttClientOptions = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                    .WithWebSocketServer(signedRequestUrl)
                    .Build();

await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(mqttClientOptions);
```

publish - works

```
var applicationMessage = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
            .WithTopic(topic)
            .WithPayload("test")
            .Build();

var resp = await mqttClient.PublishAsync(applicationMessage);
```

subscribe - fails with `MqttClientDisconnectedException` using either of the following

```
var result = await mqttClient.SubscribeAsync(new MqttTopicFilterBuilder().WithTopic(topic).Build());

var result = await mqttClient.SubscribeAsync(topic);
```

I've tried numerous different options when creating the client and calling subscribe, and the result is always the same

I believe another one of our devs has been able to get both publish and subscribe working in a web app with a javascript library, but I don't know the details (its the weekend)

MQTT is new to me so I might be missing something obvious.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you have a build error when applying a filter.  Maybe your filter is bad.  See if this helps : https://community.infineon.com/t5/AIROC-Wi-Fi-MCUs/Wi-Fi-MQTT-Client-example-build-errors/td-p/406122

Comment: Why do you think that?  I get the same behavior if I simply use the topic string directly in the Subscribe method.  I don't see anything in the linked page that applies to what I'm doing.

Comment: The one that fails has "new MqttTopicFilterBuilder().WithTopic(topic)" and the one that works doesn't.

Comment: one is a `Publish` and the other is `Subscribe`.  They have completely different signatures

Comment: Still the filter is failing.  Publish in working so the connection is good, and the server is running.

Comment: see my edit - it fails using either overload for `Subscribe`

Comment: Can you successfully subscribe from another app (e.g. [mosquitto_sub](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/use-aws-iot-core-mqtt-broker-with-standard-mqtt-libraries/#temp:C:FMS37fdd67afc7761d59d458a803))?. If not I'd guess this is a permissions issue.

Comment: As I said, we’ve been able to subscribe with a js library (but don’t know all the details)

Comment: The link above is to the amazon docs showing how to test with `mosquitto_sub` so it should be a quick test to confirm if it's an issue with your code or something else (as you say you don't know the details, so the JS test may be using a different topic).

Comment: Can you get the status code from result?  It should be 200 OK or a 400/500 error.

Comment: the `MqttClientSubscribeResult` object does not have an HTTP status code

Comment: There were some issues in compatibility between MqttNet and AWS, you might want to look through them, to see if something applies to you. E.g. https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet/issues/1729